# How to make a icon is showed only once?

Tags: ios

There is a red icon in a cell but want to show it **once**.
I set a bool value as a flag in the viewDidLoad and applicationWillEnterForeground: functions.

But it couldn't make sure the red icon disappear once it was appeared before.

Give a solution to reach this target.
The system is iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to show the red icon only once ever in your application or just in one lifecycle of the app?

Comment: and what makes it disappear? time, or another action?

Comment: Use NSUserDefaults

Comment: only once ever in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the viewWillAppear method.

Set the flag after entering this method for the first time.

After this set your icon to hidden when you enter the method again.

Comment: it doesn't function when I entered an application from the background to the foreground.

Comment: If you go to background, the flag should keep its value. So the solution will still work.

What is your problem, in what way does your app behave wrongly?

Comment: The flag keeps its value as you think. But it won't entered the function of viewWillAppear when I entered app from background to the foreground. So I should do the UI operation in another function and get the flag: applicationWillEnterForeground: I have solved this problem.Thanks all.